# ImageMagick mogrify stopped working with a great amount of images

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, file-conversion, mogrify

When using

```
mogrify -format png *.ppm
```

with a couple of images it works, but when I tried with a great amount of files(Around 20 million) it does not show an error message but after a some minutes the CLI will appear as if it had finished the task but when checking my folder I do not have a single png, I work in windows and have 8 Gigabytes of RAM, so I was wondering:

**Does ImageMagick has a limit for the quantity of images?**

Or is it just that my computer is not powerful enough for the task?

The files have around 400 Megabytes in total.

Also if there is any other way to get the images into png format even if losing the ppm version please let me know.

Comment: It could be your file system cannot handle that many files. I do not know of any limit on the number of files to process, since mogrify takes them one at a time. Do you have any bad files? Are there any huge files?  Is your temp space full?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your ImageMagick `policy.xml` file?

It should be at `homeDirectory/.config/ImageMagick/policy.xml`

There are limitations that you can set in that file.

Might want to check [Imagemagick security policy page](https://imagemagick.org/script/security-policy.php)

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas...

Firstly, use:

```
mogrify -verbose -format png *.ppm
```

so you see what's going on.

Secondly, you could try creating a list of files to process like this:

```
DIR *.ppm /S /B > filelist.txt
```

Then tell **ImageMagick** to process that list of files with:

```
mogrify -format png @filelist.txt
```

Another idea... try using double quotes:

```
mogrify -format png "*.ppm"
```